# Problem with spacing RMarkdown pdf after list (unordered, ordered)

Tags: r, r-markdown

I encountered a problem with Rmarkdown, The line spacing is too large, doubled.

I mean exactly spacing between point 2. and item 1 in unordered list and between item 2 and subitem A as in attached screenshot.

How can I prevent it?

I'm using R 3.6.3 on Mac osx.

[image: knitted pdf]

Below is Rmarkdown reproducible example:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
date: "11/19/2023"
output: pdf_document
---



1. the vehicle will be released at California
2. and return after the expiry of the rental in California
  - Item 1:
  - Item 2:
    + Subitem A
    + Subitem B
    + Subitem C
    
The Lessor declares that the vehicle being the subject of the rental is insured in the scope of Third Party Liability, has a valid technical inspection, is technically efficient and has no damages, which the Lessee verified by signing the contract. 

3. The Lessor declares that the vehicle being the subject of the rental is insured in the scope of Third Party Liability, has a valid technical inspection, is technically efficient and has no damages, which the Lessee verified by signing the contract. 
```{r, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, tidy=TRUE}
library(kableExtra)
g<-data.frame("day"= c("Mon", "Tue"), time = c("8:00", "12:00"))

colnames(g)<-NULL
kable(g, format = "latex")
````

Comment: I cannot replicate the separation between the first and second list, with a windows setup.

Comment: I'm on a MAC setup, and the spacing looks appropriate to me, too. I'm using r 4.3.1, though.